# Compiling other JVM languages in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, frege

I'm trying to write Android applications in Frege and I currently have the gradle compiling the project after evaluation like this:

```
project.afterEvaluate {
    extensions.compileFrege = {
        description = 'Compile Frege to Java'
        javaexec {
            configurations.compile.resolve().each {
                classpath += files(it.toString())
                println it.toString()
            }
            main = 'frege.compiler.Main'
            def a = ['-j', '-target', '1.7', '-v', '-inline', '-d', 'src/main/java', '-make', '-sp', 'src/main/frege/io/github/mchav/freoquiz','src/main/frege/io/github/mchav/freoquiz' 
            println 'Frege compiler args: "' + a.join(' ') + '"'
            args (*a)
        }
    }
    compileFrege()
}
```

The problem with this is that it doesn't see the Android API (which I have to add manually to compile dependencies) and it can't use any of the `aar` files such as support because the compilations happens before they are "exploded." So I'd like to compile Frege files in place of Java files and set a default compiler for my project.

I imagine Android Studio, at some point, runs `javac` how can I replace it with a custom compile command?

Comment: I don't believe it does run javac. Android doesn't run on the JVM, it runs on Dalvik or ART depending on the version of the OS.